# While loop overwrites data every time, how can I work around this?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have the following problem.
I want to set up a report button with Ajax, this passes certain variables like comment ID, creater from comment.

As I said I have implemented this with Ajax, so far all good.

I have as POST in another PHP file my PHP code.

I have a While loop in which I output all the data from the database.

Now I want to save and pass this data via SESSION, but this data is overwritten by the While loop every time, how do I fix this?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM threadComments WHERE subThreadsID = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC ");
$stmt->execute([$page]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $createdComments = $row['created_at'];
    $idComment = $row['id'];
    $userlike = $row['userlike'];
    $userid = $row['userid'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $dateNow = date_create($createdComments, timezone_open('Europe/Berlin'));
    $timeNow = time();
    $seconds = strtotime($createdComments);
    $diffSeconds = $timeNow - $seconds;
    $date = date_format($dateNow, 'd.m.Y - H:i');

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT userid, userImage FROM users WHERE userid = ?");
    $statement->execute([$userid]);
    $rowImages = $statement->fetch();
    extract($rowImages);


    $string = $row['threadContent'];
    $string = convertHashtags($string);
    
    HTML /////

    $_SESSION['commentContent'] = $string;
    $_SESSION['commentCreaterID'] = $row['userid'];
    $_SESSION['commentID'] = $row['id'];

}
?>
```

Comment: Make each session variable an array and push onto it.

Comment: Or use one session variable that's a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @Barmar How can I do that? Can you show me examples?

Comment: The same way you push onto any other array., `$_SESSION['commentContent'][] = $string;`

Answer (score 0):

Put them into an array in `$_SESSION`. Make it an associative array so you can get the data for a particular comment id with `$_SESSION['comments'][$id]`

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM threadComments WHERE subThreadsID = ? ORDER BY created_at DESC ");
$stmt->execute([$page]);
$_SESSION['comments'] = [];
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $createdComments = $row['created_at'];
    $idComment = $row['id'];
    $userlike = $row['userlike'];
    $userid = $row['userid'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $dateNow = date_create($createdComments, timezone_open('Europe/Berlin'));
    $timeNow = time();
    $seconds = strtotime($createdComments);
    $diffSeconds = $timeNow - $seconds;
    $date = date_format($dateNow, 'd.m.Y - H:i');

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT userid, userImage FROM users WHERE userid = ?");
    $statement->execute([$userid]);
    $rowImages = $statement->fetch();
    extract($rowImages);


    $string = $row['threadContent'];
    $string = convertHashtags($string);
    
    HTML /////

    $_SESSION['comments'][$row['id']] = [
        'content' => $string,
        'creatorID' => $row['userid'],
        'commentID' => $row['id']
    ];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how do I access exactly the comment that was reported?

Here all comments are stored in a variable.

When the user reports a comment, I would only need the data from the ID (example) 5.

Comment: You could make it an associative array where the ID is the key.

Comment: Yes, I have now saved the session into a variable, there I can access the data with [0]['creatorID']. The problem I have now is, how do I pass the correct number of my comment so that I can report the correct comments.

Comment: Put the ID in a hidden form field.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I am completely confused now. 

in my array no ID is stored.

exampleArray[NUMBER OF DATA][DATA I WANT TO ACCESS]

How do I now know that my comment X Y Z is number 2 in my array?

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it an associative array.

Comment: Thanks!  But how do I pass when the button was reported by the comment with the ID 342 that my script in report_comment.php
i want to pass the row['id'].

Comment: Use a hidden input: `<input name="commentid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">`

Comment: i would also use this for the future, is it safe?

Comment: Safe in what way? It's the normal way to pass information to the client so it can pass it back to the server. Of course, you need to do validation, to make sure they're allowed to update that comment.